# Add the Rules Editor to a Speak Application (for Sitecore Forms Submit Action)

Tags: speak

Is there a way to place the Rules Editor in a Speak Application (so the user can define custom rule logic, ie. in this case I want to perform custom logic on the submit action, based on rules defined for the submit action).

Rules Editor I'm referring to:
[image]

I looked through the Speak v2 renderings, but I don't see that type of control.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you write out a use case? I'm not following how you would use the rule editor selection in a submit action.

Comment: @PeteNavarra I'll be honest, this wasn't the direction I was originally going to take, but thought this might be easier and more flexible.  Use cases are plentiful, to be able to have conditional submit actions based on fields entered.  Such as if there is a dropdown on the form, if option A could send an e-mail to e-mail campaign A, and option b to email campaign b, etc.  And of course, there are plenty of other scenarios I can think of including, conditional goals, redirects, based on submitted data or parameters passed to the form (via qstring) etc.